# How to get depth of hierarchical data with linq query?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of hierarchical data like this:

```
var list = new List<Data>(){some data...}

class Data
{
    public int number;
    public List<Data> info;
}
```

Note: Data in leaf of tree -->`info = null`

**Example:**

numbers are `number property` of Data class

```
   --1
      --11
   --2
      --21
      --22
      --23
      --24
   --3
      --31
      --32
          --321
          --322
   --4
      --41
      --42
```

How to know max depth of tree with **linq** query(Not Recursive method or for loop ) to list of data?

in this example max level is 3 for 321,322

Thanks.

Comment: LINQ is designed for linear sequences of data, not recursive data structures. What's wrong with a recursive method?

Comment: No wrong, I curious to solve this problem with linq.

Comment: @RezaArab, I doubt this is even possible with linq, for reasons dtb explained.

Comment: Specially in linq to Entities to achieve this with one query to database, I can't use Recursive Method.

Comment: @RezaArab, explain why you cant use recursion and it might help it find another solution.

Comment: In real this problem exist in linq to entities,If i want to solve this with recursive data, must get all entities(low performance) and then recurs it. i want to calculate depth with a query to database with less data transfer.

Comment: You have a recursive data structure - you're going to need some form of recursion to traverse the data.

Comment: Also i think use of Mapping Functions for calculation and call it in Linq to entities can solve problem without traverse data, Right?

Comment: @Enigmativity is right. What I have seen, database views encapsulating a recusive query with a common table expression is the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ and SQL operate on flat data structures; they are not designed for recursive data structures.

With LINQ to Entities, I believe you're out of luck. Store the depth of the subtree in each node and recursively update it whenever you insert/delete a node.

With LINQ to Objects, you could define a recursive extension method that returns all paths in a tree and take the length of the longest path:

```
var result = root.Paths().Max(path => path.Length);
```

where

```
public static IEnumerable<Data[]> Paths(this Data data)
{
    return Paths(data, new[] { data });
}

private static IEnumerable<Data[]> Paths(Data data, Data[] path)
{
    return new[] { path }.Concat((data.info ?? Enumerable.Empty<Data>())
    .SelectMany(child => Paths(child, path.Concat(new[] { child }).ToArray())));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All Linq operators use a loop in some way so it is not possible to solve with linq if the requirement is no loop.

It is possible without recursion. You just need a stack. Something like

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<int, T>> FlattenWithDepth<T>(T root, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> children) {
    var stack = new Stack<Tuple<int, T>>();

    stack.Push(Tuple.Create(1, root));

    while (stack.Count > 0) {
        var node = stack.Pop();

        foreach (var child in children(node.Item2)) {
            stack.Push(Tuple.Create(node.Item1+1, child));
        }
        yield return node;
    }
}
```

Your linq query will then be

```
FlattenWithDepth(root, x => x.info ?? Enumerable.Empty<Data>()).Max(x => x.Item1);
```

(sorry don't have a compiler available to verify)

** Edit. Just saw that you had multiple roots **

```
list.SelectMany(y => FlattenWithDepth(y, x => x.info ?? Enumerable.Empty<Data>()))
    .Max(x => x.Item1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following would work:

```
internal static class ListDataExtension
{
    public static int MaxDepthOfTree(this List<Data> dataList)
    {
        return dataList.Max(data => data.MaxDepthOfTree);
    }
}
internal class Data
{
    public int number;
    public List<Data> info;

    public int MaxDepthOfTree
    {
        get 
        { 
            return GetDepth(1); 
        }
    }

    int GetDepth(int depth)
    {
        if (info == null)
            return depth;
        var maxChild = info.Max(x => x.GetDepth(depth));
        return maxChild + 1;
    }
}
```

Then just call:

```
var maxDepth = list.MaxDepthOfTree();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you should use it in DB, I would suggest add additional column to your DB to save the depth of tree, there are some situation which depth changes:

1. Adding new element, its depth is FatherDepth + 1.
2. Delete: If this is cascade relation there is no problem with deleting, but if it's not cascade you should write a recursive query to update children's depth.

For finding depth just run a query to find the maximum depth value.